# static int em classe C++

Tags: c++

Olá, o seguinte código está apresentando o erro a direita:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class teste {
    static int x;
    public:
        teste () {
            x++;
        }
}  t1;

int main () {

    return 0;
}
```

declaro a variável static int, e no método construtor eu incremento +1, mas acontece o seguinte erro.

Como resolver?

OBS: No livro que estou lendo o código está assim também.

Comment: [**Não coloque o código como imagem!**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483)

Comment: Editado, desculpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Membros de dados estáticos são armazenados separadamente, como se não fizessem parte do objeto. Por isso devem declararados fora da da sua classe.

```
class teste {
    static int x;
    public:
        teste () {
            x++;
        }
}  t1;

int teste::x = 0;
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora funcionou ;)